# Can you wake up the device when publishing a card?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a background service that pushes live cards to the Glass. The device plays a tone when a card is published, but I would also like to wake the device up for a few moments. Is this possible without acquiring a wakelock?

Comment: I ended up using wakelock.aquire(1); Just long enough for the device to kick on, and means i dont have to manage the wakelock myself, though i do double check in onDestroy just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't recommend that features as you can read here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/design/principles

Pay attention at this points:

> - **Avoid the Unexpected:**
>
> Unexpected functionality and bad experiences on Glass are much worse than on other    devices, because Glass is so close to your users' senses.
>
> - **Don't get in the way:**
>
> Glass is designed to be there when you need it and out of the way when you don't. Your Glassware must function in the same way. Offer engaging functionality that supplements the user's life without taking away from it.

Google Glass are not like a smartphones, so you should design your apps according to Google Glass principles.